# Our WordPress Auction Website increases CPU Spikes hosted in dedicated server

Tags: centos, mysql, wordpress, php.ini, load-average

We have hosted our WordPress website in the dedicated server(CENTOS 7.9 kvm [server]) with 8 CPU. Our website is auction based website. So normally 20 auctions will be in live.
But our website reaches high CPU usage and spikes. We have tried to decrease the CPU spikes with following ways

1. Disabled all installed plugin
2. Disabled cronjob
3. Disabled unwanted plugins

But still we have bottle neck and server response time is very low. Can any one help me to resolve my issue please.

Comment: For highly dynamic websites like auction sites, you want to make use of [Redis powered persistent object cache for WordPress](https://www.getpagespeed.com/web-apps/wordpress/speed-up-wordpress-with-persistent-object-cache-powered-by-latest-redis).

Comment: We have installed Redis PHP extension in our Ubuntu server. Where can we find the difference after enabling this PHP extension? Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is based on Entity-Attribute-Value schema.  EAV is a flexible schema, but that flexibility comes at a cost of performance when searching the data.

There is a partial solution to the CPU problem.  It involves changing the indexes of `postmeta`.  Details here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

(That applies to various derivatives, too, such as WooCommerce.)